# Dynamic Cell Reference For Multi Select Dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel where there is multiple same dropdown in a column like below:

[Multi select dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABKye.png)

Now, I have a VBA code that allow for multi selection of item in the dropdown. Right now, the multi select only enable in the first dropdown and not the others.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Code by Sumit Bansal from https://trumpexcel.com
' To allow multiple selections in a Drop Down List in Excel (without repetition)
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

How do I change the `Target.Address = "$C$2"` into C4,C5,C6,Cn.... ???

Comment: You will need to explain what you mean by "dynamic" - if it shouldn't be C2 then how is it determined what it *should* be?   FYI  `If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0` may fail as soon as one of your items is a substring of another item...

Comment: Instead of `If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then` you can use `Select Case Target.Address : Case "$C$2", "$C$3", ... /*any other address of interest*/: /*your code here*/ : End Select`